# Unix piping in system() does not work in R

Tags: r, linux, awk, sh

I am using the system() command to run a Bash command in R, but every time I try to pipe the results of one command into the next (using '|'), I get some error.

For example:
`system('grep ^SN bam_stats.txt | cut -f 2- | sed -n 8p | awk -F "\t" '{print $2}'')` returns the error: `Error: unexpected '{' in "system('grep ^SN bam_stats.txt | cut -f 2- | sed -n 8p | awk -F "\t" '{"`, and if I try to remove `awk -F "\t" '{print $2}'` so that I'm left with `system('grep ^SN bam_stats.txt | cut -f 2- | sed -n 8p')`, I get the following:

`/usr/bin/grep: 2-: No such file or directory`

`[1] 2`

I have to keep removing parts of it till I am left with only `system('grep ^SN bam_stats.txt')`, AKA no pipes are left, for it to work.

Here is a sample from the file 'bam_stats.txt' from which I'm extracting information:

```
SN  filtered sequences: 0
SN  sequences:  137710356
SN  is sorted:  1
SN  1st fragments:  68855178
SN  last fragments: 68855178
SN  reads mapped:   137642653
SN  reads mapped and paired:    137602018   # paired-end technology bit set + both mates mapped
SN  reads unmapped: 67703
SN  percentage of properly paired reads (%):    99.8
```

Can someone tell me why piping is not working? Apologies if this is a stupid question. Please let me know if I should provide more information.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does `system('echo hello | cat')` in R emit `hello` or `hello | cat` on stdout? If it's the former, pipes are being honored.

Comment: ...https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html does explicitly document that `system()` should use `/bin/sh` in R on UNIXy systems, so we don't need to worry about whether R has a function it called `system()` that doesn't actually start a shell.

Comment: Now, your _original_ error makes much more sense -- it's because you're trying to put literal single-quotes inside a single-quoted string (so why the awk didn't work makes sense; how to escape single-quotes in a string is a very language-specific thing, and you'd need someone who knows R to answer it).

Comment: That said, `system()` **doesn't use bash**, it uses `sh`. This question should be tagged `sh`, not bash. They're two different shells, and while bash is _mostly_ a superset of POSIX sh, that doesn't mean they're fully compatible.

Comment: @G5W, yup, I point that out [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68966550/unix-piping-in-system-does-not-work-in-r#comment121885477_68966550). That problem isn't surprising; the failure of `system('grep ^SN bam_stats.txt | cut -f 2- | sed -n 8p')`, on the other hand, is surprising.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know R but IF Rs implementation of `system()` just passes it's argument to a shell then, in terms of standard Unix quoting, your example

```
system('grep ^SN bam_stats.txt | cut -f 2- | sed -n 8p | awk -F "\t" '{print $2}'')
```

contains 2 strings within quotes and a string in the middle that's outside of quotes:

- Inside: `grep ^SN bam_stats.txt | cut -f 2- | sed -n 8p | awk -F "\t"`
- Outside: `{print $2}`
- Inside: `<a null string>`

because the 2 quotes in the middle around `'{print $2}'` are ending the first quoted string then later starting a second quoted string.

You don't need sed, grep, or cut if you're using awk anyway though so try just this:

```
system('awk -F"\t" "/^SN/ && (++cnt==8){print \$3}" bam_stats.txt')
```

Comment: Looks like `system("awk -F'\t' '/^SN/ && (++cnt==8) {print $3}' bam_stats.txt")` should also work, which avoids the additional escaping of the `$`.

Comment: @chepner true, but idk if `R` allows double quotes around their `system()` args. Awk, for example, allows `system("foo")` but not `system('foo')` , and the OP showed that R allows `system('foo')` so I just went with that as idk if `system("foo")` is allowed or not.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_strings.htm, at least, suggests that you can use single or double quotes to define a string. Oddly enough, it seems like the *only* way to include quote in a string is to use the other. It doesn't mention any kind of backslash escaping. (Pretty much everything I know about R is in this comment section, so take anything I say with a huge grain of salt.)

Comment: Interesting, so I guess they must use `\042` and `\047` or similar for double and single quotes inside strings with the same delimiter.

Comment: I was wondering about something like that, but didn't dig further.

Comment: Or maybe they allow concatenation like in shell `'foo'\''bar'`? Who knows... I think I've contributed all I can to this question :-).

Comment: Thank you for your response. The command you provided works for the example I sent, however in other examples involving piping, it doesn't. For instance, I want to run the following command: `grep -P "^chr" 20D0001.vcf | awk '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c` to get the frequency of each chromosome in the VCF file. Again, piping does not work, and I don't know how to modify the command you provided to do that.

Comment: You can do that all in 1 awk command too, e.g. `awk "/^chr/{cnt[\$1]++} END{for (chr in cnt) print chr, cnt[chr]}"` or equivalent, so if no-one who knows `R` can help with your pipelines you could probably just learn awk,